# Reading binary data in float32

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to train a network using Tensorflow, based on features from a time signal. Data is split up in `E` 3 second epochs with `F` features for each epoch. Thus, the data has the form

```
Epoch | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | ... | Feature F |
-------------------------------------------------
1     | ..        | ..        |     | ..        |
      | ..        | ..        |     | ..        |
E     | ..        | ..        |     | ..        |
```

Loading data to Tensorflow, I am trying to follow the cifar example and using `tf.FixedLengthRecordReader`. Thus, I have taken the data, and saved it to a binary file of type `float32` with first label for the first epoch, followed by the `F` features for the first epoch, then the second, etc.

Reading this into Tensorflow is a challenge for me, however. Here is my code:

```
def read_data_file(file_queue):

    class DataRecord(object):
        pass

    result = DataRecord()

    #1 float32 as label => 4 bytes
    label_bytes = 4

    #NUM_FEATURES as float32 => 4 * NUM_FEATURES
    features_bytes = 4 * NUM_FEATURES

    #Create the read operator with the summed amount of bytes
    reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=label_bytes+features_bytes)

    #Perform the operation
    result.key, value = reader.read(file_queue)

    #Decode the result from bytes to float32
    value_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.float32, little_endian=True)

    #Cast label to int for later
    result.label = tf.cast(tf.slice(value_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)

    #Cast features to float32
    result.features = tf.cast(tf.slice(value_bytes, [label_bytes],
        [features_bytes]), tf.float32)

    print ('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>')
    print ('%s' % result.label)
    print ('%s' % result.features)
    print ('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>')
```

Print output was:

```
Tensor("Cast:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(4)]), dtype=int32)
Tensor("Slice_1:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(40)]), dtype=float32)
```

Which surprises me, because since I have cast the values to float32, I expected the dimensions to be respectively 1 and 10, which are the actual numbers, but they are 4 and 40, which corresponds to the byte lengths.

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue stems from the fact that `tf.decode_raw(value, tf.float32, little_endian=True)` returns a vector of type `tf.float32` rather than a vector of bytes. The slice size for extracting the features should be specified as a count of floating-point values (i.e. `NUM_FEATURES`) rather than a count of bytes (`features_bytes`).

However, there's the slight wrinkle that your label is an integer, while the rest of the vector contains floating-point values. TensorFlow doesn't have many facilities for casting between binary representations (except [`tf.decode_raw()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_raw)), so you'll have to decode the string twice into different types:

```
# Decode the result from bytes to int32
value_as_ints = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.int32, little_endian=True)
result.label = value_as_ints[0]

# Decode the result from bytes to float32
value_as_floats = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.float32, little_endian=True)
result.features = value_as_floats[1:1+NUM_FEATURES]
```

Note that this only works because `sizeof(tf.int32) == sizeof(tf.float32)`, which wouldn't be true in general. Some more string manipulation tools would be useful for slicing out appropriate substrings of the raw `value` in the more general case. Hopefully this should be enough to get you going, though.